# Decompiling an executable compiled by vercel/pkg

Tags: ghidra, decompile, javascript

I have a .exe file that I am trying to get the source code of, After some digging I figured out that it's in node.js and was compiled using [vercel/pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg)
I tried using [pkg-unpacker](https://github.com/LockBlock-dev/pkg-unpacker) however the output is all messed up and have a lot of null characters, even the node-modules modules have null characters in them, Only the *.js files have null characters, *.json are fine and are in their default format
I also saw used a hex editor but that code isn't human-readable at all

Some people suggested using [ghidra_nodejs](https://github.com/PositiveTechnologies/ghidra_nodejs) which will be my next step, however I don't know how to use it or if it will work with all the weird characters in the *.js files
I think that the project is obfuscated using https://obfuscator.io/ or https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator
Any Ideas/Help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `vercel/pkg` tool takes javascript (node.js) code, compiles it into `v8` *bytecode* and wraps it in an executable code that matches the platform.

As the Github page of the pkg-unpacker tool states:

> This application DOES NOT decompile any code. By default pkg compiles code to V8 bytecode. Extracted files will remain in this format except for assets.

Included `.json` files are assets, so they are decoded into their original readable form. The code remains as *v8 bytecode*.

The mentioned Ghidra plugin can disassemble and/or decompile it into readable format for analysis.

There is a detailed article about reverse engineering this type of code here:

https://swarm.ptsecurity.com/how-we-bypassed-bytenode-and-decompiled-node-js-bytecode-in-ghidra/